# Drop columns which contains specific words (not as a substring)

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame, `df`:

```
id     text
1      'a little table'
2      'blue lights'
3      'food and drink'
4      'build an atom'
5      'fast animals'
```

and a list of stop words, that is:

```
sw = ['a', 'an', 'and']
```

I want to delete the lines that contain at least one of the stop words (as words themselves, not as substrings). That is, the result I would like is:

```
id     text
2      'blue lights'
5      'fast animals'
```

I was trying with:

```
df[~df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(sw), regex=True, na=False)]
```

but it doesn't seem to work, as it works with substrings this way, and `a` is substring of all texts (except for 'blue lights'). How should I change my line of code?

Comment: Your code should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# '|'.join(sw)  : creates a string with a |, to form an OR condition
# \\b : adds the word boundary to the capture group
```

```
# create a pattern surrounded by the word boundary and then 
# filtered out what is found using loc
df.loc[~df['text'].str.contains('\\b('+ '|'.join(sw) + ')\\b' )]
```

OR

```
df[df['text'].str.extract('\\b('+ '|'.join(sw) + ')\\b' )[0].isna()]
```

```
    id  text
1   2   'blue lights'
4   5   'fast animals'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
li = ['a', 'an', 'and']
for i in li:
    for k in df.index:
        if i in df.text[k].split():
            df.drop(k,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), you could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 
        'text': {0: "'a little table'", 1: "'blue lights'", 
                 2: "'food and drink'", 3: "'build an atom'", 
                 4: "'fast animals'"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sw = ['a', 'an', 'and']
res = df[~df['text'].str.contains(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(sw)})\b', 
                                  regex=True, na=False)]

print(res)

   id            text
1   2   'blue lights'
4   5  'fast animals'
```

In the regex pattern `\b` asserts position at a word boundary, while `?:` at start of pattern between `(...)` creates a `non-capturing group`. Strictly speaking, you could do without `?:`, but it suppresses a `Userwarning`: "This pattern ... has match groups etc.".
`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which works as follows:

1. Split each string by space, producing a list of words
2. Check whether each of those lists of words is disjoint with `sw`.
3. Use the result for boolean indexing.

```
df[df['text'].str.split(' ').map(lambda x: set(x).isdisjoint(sw))]
```

Output:

```
   id          text
1   2   blue lights
4   5  fast animals
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the custom apply() method,

```
def string_present(List,string):
    return any(ele+' ' in string for ele in List)

df['status'] = df['text'].apply(lambda row: string_present(sw,row))
df[df['status']==False].drop(columns=['status'],axis=1)
```

The output is,

```
   id          text
1   2   blue lights
4   5  fast animals
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sw = ['a', 'an', 'and']
df1.loc[~df1.text.str.split(' ').map(lambda x:pd.Series(x).isin(sw).any())]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.